# unpickle files, for loading datasets to use on my CNN

Tags: python, keras

I'll try to make it clear as can be.

I've tried to download **cifar10 dataset** using :

`from keras.datasets import cifar10`

I had a problem and I read that a lot of users have this problem.

So, I kept on going, and download the dataset directly, I got five data_batch files, 1 test_batch, and 1 batches.meta file.

After that point, I looked online and saw that I need to "unpickle" (never heard this expression before), so I found this little function:

```
def unpickle(file):
  import pickle
  with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
       dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
  return dict here
```

So far so good,now I'm trying to use this function correctly:

```
 def load_data():
    x_l = []
    y_l = []
    for j in range(5):
        d = unpickle('data/data_batch_' + repr(j + 1))
        xx = d['data']
        yy = d['labels']
    x_l.append(xx)
    y_l.append(yy)
    d = unpickle('data/test_batch')
    x_l.append(d['data'])
    y_l.append(d['labels'])

    return x_l, y_l
```

And I'm calling the function load_data using this line:

```
xs, ys = load_data()
```

But I'm getting an error on this line:

```
xx = d['data']
```

And the biggest problem, Is that I'm getting a simple error, which I can't deduce and understand where I'm getting wrong, this is the error:

> xx = d['data']
>
> KeyError: 'data'

this is how d looks like after assigning him this:

`unpickle('data/data_batch_' + repr(j + 1))`

[image]

I really need your help, I want to understand what am I doing wrong because I'm to use this functionality a lot.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyError is straightforward, and this one looks like it is related to a dictionary key being encoded as byte object.  I assume you are using Python2. Switching to Python3 solves the problem. For Python2, try calling data[b'data'] instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using python 3.6, I'll edit the post, It's important to mention.

Comment: I am just guessing here but did you try ruling out encoding problem? i.e. changing the encoding to ASCII or do xx = d[b'data']??

Comment: xx = d[b'data'] -> your correct! I was so sure that it's should be just 'data'..
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading dataset like this:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the top of the post I tried this method, and I always had a problem/ and after reading about the problem online, I saw a lot of users having this problem and there is no straight solution.